# Intuitive explanation for why the group $S_n$ has $n!$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's not entirely obvious to me that the group of permutations of a set A under permutation multiplication / function composition has $n!$ functions in it. Would someone be able to provide an intuitive explanation?

I am taking an undergraduate course on abstract algebra at the moment.

Comment: what did you tried to prove it ?

Comment: Think about it this way.  Such a function is determined if you specify where the first element goes ($n$ choices) and after choosing that choose where the 2nd element goes ($n-1$ remaining choices) and the next will have $n-2$ choices, etc..  Total number of possibilities is therefore $n\cdot(n-1)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1$

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Actually, I thought about this soon after I posted the question and realized a visual proof quite quickly. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: The chosen response in the referenced page to the same question was essentially exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of $S_{n}$ as the group that maps the string $[1, 2, 3, 4, ...., n]$ to another string $[\pi(1), \pi(2), ..., \pi(n)]$ via some element $\pi$ in the permutation group.  Then think about how many choices you have for the value $\pi(1)$, there are $n$ choices.  Once that choice is made, you have $n-1$ choices for $\pi(2)$, then $n-2$ choices for $\pi(3)$, etc.  Then the total number of choices you have are $n(n-1)(n-2)...(1)=n!$.  Each distinct set of choices corresponds to a distinct permutation in the group.  Hence there are $n!$ permutations in the group.

Comment: I think the best way to give someone an "intuition" on such a proof, is to bring him to do the problem himself. I am not sure it is so good that you repeat the "answer", which has given many times on MSE already.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I agree that the OP should look for questions already existing here first.  But, if there were some rule "not to ask questions that have already been asked" then there'd essentially be very few new questions (especially here, not so much on mathoverflow).

Comment: But there is indeed a rule that duplicates should be closed. I find this also reasonable, because otherwise it is just only copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of computing the number of elements in $S_n$ is the same as that of computing the number of different ways the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$ can be placed in the $n$ blanks indicated (using each integer just once):
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3& \cdots & n-1 & n\\
- & - & - & \cdots &- & -
\end{pmatrix}
If we begin filling these blanks from the left, there are $n$ possibilities for the first blank. Once that choice has been made, there remain $n-1$ possibilities for the second blank. Then there are $n-2$ possibilities for the third blank, and so on. The theorem follows by repeated application of this basic counting principle: If one thing can be done in $r$ different ways, and after that a second thing can be done in $s$ different ways, then the two things can be done together in $rs$ different ways.